# HTML 5 - User specific cache (images)

Tags: html, caching, manifest

I use HTML 5 cache (a ".manifest" file) to cache stuff on my website, like pages/images/script/css and so on. These files are the same for all the users that logs into the system = no problem.

But on one page there is a lot of images loading (user specific), so no users views the same images. It takes a lot of time to load those images and nearly *allways* it is the same images that are loaded - so I want to cache them so to page would load faster.

Can I do this with HTML 5 cache? and how? Or maybe by some other method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this can be generating dynamic appcache manifest file on the server before sending the response. In that appcache file you can mention user specific images.

Comment: Found this link (thanks to your guidance) should work - right?
http://richardleggett.co.uk/blog/2011/09/26/dynamic-application-cache-manifest-for-php/